# How can I add resizable widgets in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qwidget

How can I add resizable widgets in Qt Creator?

Specially widgets in `QVBoxLayout` or `QHBoxLayout`

Comment: Are you creating new widgets or you are asking how to make the widgets re sizable?

Comment: @André Puel: How to make widgets resizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget* w = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout;
    w->setLayout(l);
    QPushButton* b = new QPushButton("hello");
    b->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    l->addWidget(b);
    w->show();    

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use layouts if you want that your widgets are resizable:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: I've been added QVBoxLayout in Form int QtCreator at design mode, but it's still not resizable

Comment: Your whole Form must have a layout. Right click over it and choose "Lay out"

Comment: @TheHorse: How can i do that?

Comment: widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum); or widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

Comment: Do you think the OP means resizable as in drag-resize?