# How to make a Qt widget resizable

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add resizable widgets in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195781/how-can-i-add-resizable-widgets-in-qt-creator)

I am using QTreeView and QListView and i want to make them to be sizable i.e. when i go the top end of the QTreeview the pointer should be transformed into a vertical arrow which allows me do a up resize by mouse drag and drop, a feature that is seen on many application nowadays.

How can be achieved this? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add resizable widgets in Qt Creator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7195781/594137). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7195880/594137) to that question answers yours at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your widgets into a `QSplitter`.